# Struts-2 vulnerability in Struts-1

Tags: struts2, struts, struts1

does anyone know if the vulnerabilities of struts-2 shown here : https://struts.apache.org/docs/security-bulletins.html are also applicable to struts-1?

Comment: S1 and S2 are different frameworks.

Comment: How do you apply them?

Comment: I'm not really sure, that's why I dropped the question here. I assumed that because S1 and S2 are two different things, the vulnerabilities that are found on S2 won't always apply to S1.

Comment: They are different frameworks completely. If you want to see the vulnerabilities for Struts-1, you would not look at the vulnerabilities for struts-2, and vise-versa.

Comment: roger that. thanks a lot guys.